# How can I save queries in an already created table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I know how to create table from queries:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE InstructorAddressModPer
  2  AS
  3     SELECT InstructorAddress.instructor_address_id, InstructorAddress.instructor_id, InstructorMailingAddressModPer.module_id, InstructorMailingAddressModPer.student_id
  4     FROM InstructorAddress
  5     LEFT JOIN InstructorMailingAddressModPer ON InstructorAddress.instructor_id = InstructorMailingAddressModPer.instructor_id;
```

But how can I use queries to save values into an already created table?

Comment: replace `CREATE TABLE InstructorAddressModPer
AS` to `insert into InstructorAddressModPer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT ...` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO InstructorAddressModPer
SELECT InstructorAddress.instructor_address_id, InstructorAddress.instructor_id, InstructorMailingAddressModPer.module_id, InstructorMailingAddressModPer.student_id
  FROM InstructorAddress
  LEFT JOIN InstructorMailingAddressModPer ON InstructorAddress.instructor_id = InstructorMailingAddressModPer.instructor_id;
```